# Hough transform in MATLAB without using hough function ,error as maximum variable size exceeded

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I found an implementation of the Hough transform in MATLAB at [rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Example%3aHough_transform/MATLAB) Code, but that program is written as function. I changed that as following (the parameters are implicitly given)

```
cdata=imread('p.png');
thetaSampleFrequency=1/2000;
cdata =im2bw(cdata);
[y,x]=find(cdata);

    theImage=cdata;
    %Define the hough space
    theImage = flipud(theImage);
    [width,height] = size(theImage);

    rhoLimit = norm([width height]);
    rho = (-rhoLimit:1:rhoLimit);          
    theta = (0:thetaSampleFrequency:pi);

    numThetas = numel(theta);
    houghSpace = zeros(numel(rho),numThetas);

    %Find the "edge" pixels
    [xIndicies,yIndicies] = find(theImage);

    %Preallocate space for the accumulator array
    numEdgePixels = numel(xIndicies);
    accumulator = zeros(numEdgePixels,numThetas);

    %Preallocate cosine and sine calculations to increase speed. In
    %addition to precallculating sine and cosine we are also multiplying
    %them by the proper pixel weights such that the rows will be indexed by 
    %the pixel number and the columns will be indexed by the thetas.
    %Example: cosine(3,:) is 2*cosine(0 to pi)
    %         cosine(:,1) is (0 to width of image)*cosine(0)
    cosine = (0:width-1)'*cos(theta); %Matrix Outerproduct  
    sine = (0:height-1)'*sin(theta); %Matrix Outerproduct

    accumulator((1:numEdgePixels),:) = cosine(xIndicies,:) + sine(yIndicies,:);

    %Scan over the thetas and bin the rhos 
    for i = (1:numThetas)
        houghSpace(:,i) = hist(accumulator(:,i),rho);
    end

    pcolor(theta,rho,houghSpace);
    shading flat;
    title('Hough Transform');
    xlabel('Theta (radians)');
    ylabel('Rho (pixels)');
    colormap('GRAY');
% end
```

But I am getting the error

> > ??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
> >
> > Error in ==> edited_hough at 24
>
> ```
> accumulator = zeros(numEdgePixels,numThetas);
> ```

how to correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check what your values of `numEdgePixels`,`numThetas` are at the point you call `zeros`.

Then `[C,MAXSIZE] = computer` and check what your maximum allowed number of elements is (this will vary depending on your system and version - e.g. 32 bit vs 64 bit MATLAB).  If `numEdgePixels*numThetas>MAXSIZE` then you will always see that error.

I suspect the real reason you're getting the error is that `numEdgePixels` is too large, and it is too large is because you aren't correctly preprocessing your image.

That is, the original code you borrowed says:

> This solution takes an image and the theta resolution as inputs. The
>   image itself must be a 2-D boolean array. This array is constructed
>   such that all of the pixels on an edge have the value "true." This can
>   be done for a normal image using an "edge finding" algorithm to
>   preprocess the image.

Whereas all you're doing is calling `im2bw`, which is not an edge finding technique. Use `edge` or something instead.

Comment: preprocessed image as " cdata=edge(cdata); "  but now this code works for sample image shown in that site. but getting error messege for other images.(error is shown below)also, I cheked the no: of edge pixels. It is 12891 error: "??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> edited_hough at 37
    accumulator((1:numEdgePixels),:) = cosine(xIndicies,:) +
    sine(yIndicies,:);"